# Yacc, different execution for if part of if an if/else syntax

Tags: yacc

Following code gives "IFST2 rule is useless due to conficts" error. I am trying to print different things for if part of if and if/else blocks. How can I do this?

```
 IFST1:IF     {printf("if begin");};
 IFST2:IF     {printf("ifelse begin");};
 ELSEST:ELSE {};


singlestatement:
  '{' statement '}';
|
IFST1 '(' expr ')' singlestatement ELSEST singlestatement {};
|
IFST2 '(' expr ')' singlestatement %prec IFX {};
```

Comment: The rules for IFST1 and IFST2 are clearly ambiguous; there is nothing to differentiate them from each other.  This grammar is not going to fly until you reorganize it.  You will likely have to defer identifying on the standard output which of the two IF statement types you have until after you've processed the ELSE or not.

Comment: I guess it is impossible then. I already did something similar. now there is a stack of buffers. IF and ELSE statements changes current buffer to next one on stack. singlestatement s write on different stacks. and finally at endif part these buffers are printed in correct order and IF or IFELSE statements are correctly expanded. however this is still not enough because singlestatements can expand differently depending on if it is if or ifelse statement.

Answer (score 1):

Check [this](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/help-bison/2001-10/msg00011.html) for a general help on the issue. I think you'll have to "specialize" your case to match the general form. Though this is bison, not YACC, both are LALR parser generators.